# HTML/CSS Positioning ~ Screen Sizes/Resolution & Browser resizing

Tags: html, css

I've taken up interest in HTML/CSS Coding as of late and have run into a problem very quickly that I cant seem to solve or properly understand based on other answered questions similar to mine.
My positioning is based off pixels when it should be percent?
How to get my elements and pictures to stop rescaling as the browser shrinks, have it simply cut off like in near every website?
How do I choose between Absolute and Relative positioning?

Here's my HTML&CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D4350 , #A43931);
    background-attachment: scroll;
    
}
html, body, #wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
   
}
#content {
    height: 1200px;
}
.Octagon { 
    color: #2aa186;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.LT {
    text-align: center;
    color: #3a5454;
    line-height: 0%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.boi {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}
.boi:active {
    top: 2px;
}
.iob {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}
.boi:active, 
.iob:active {
    top: 2px;
}
#manyarms {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
}
#sensible {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
    right: 10px;
}
#verr {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-top: 285px;
    color: #6458b7;
}
#special {
    position: absolute;
    left: 77.9%;
    top: 50%;
    color: #6458b7;
}
.boi:hover,
.iob:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #a193ff;
}
#footer {
    padding-left: 95%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <title>The Pragmatic Octopus</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
     <script src='script.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
     <h1 class="Octagon">The Pragmatic Octopus</h1>
     <p class="LT">Lee Townsend</p>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="boi">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="iob">Information</p>
        </a>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/406x38nlh/imageedit_1_3827627792        .jpg" alt="mmm~" id="manyarms">
    <img src="http://www.wonderslist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Blue-ringed-octopus.jpg" alt="~mmm" id="sensible">
    <p id="verr">Here comes a very special boi!</p>
    <p id="special">He loves to pose for photos!</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    &copy; Hecc
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Either fix my code to what is desired (I'll just see what you did and understand it) or explain what I need do.
Whatever you do, thank you for reading and/or assisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change min-width: 100%; to `min-width: 1000px;` in `html, body, #wrapper` to set the min page width to 1000px. this will make the browser add a scrollbar when the window width is below 1000px.

Only applying `min-width: 1000px;` to `html, body, #wrapper` will not work for you since you also used absolute positioning. To fix this add `position: relative;` to `#wrapper`.

Why do we need to add `position: relative;` to `#wrapper`?
Absolute positioned elements will always position based on the first parent that has `position: relative;`. If none has this rule, it will just position based on the body. (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/position)

To learn more about position relative and absolute refer to: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

With those changes being made, your website will stop scaling when the browser window reaces < 1000px in width. Ofc you can change the 1000px to any width you want.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D4350 , #A43931);
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
html, body, #wrapper {
    min-width: 1000px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    /* max-width: 1200px; Edit 1 */
}
#content {
    height: 1200px;
}
.Octagon { 
    color: #2aa186;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.LT {
    text-align: center;
    color: #3a5454;
    line-height: 0%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.boi {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}
.boi:active {
    top: 2px;
}
.iob {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}
.boi:active, 
.iob:active {
    top: 2px;
}
/* Edit 2 */
#wrapperForTheFirstImage {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
}
#wrapperForTheSecondImage {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
    right: 10px;
}
/* Removed 
#manyarms {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
}
#sensible {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
    right: 10px;
} */
#verr {
    /*position: absolute;
    margin-left: 31px;
    margin-top: 285px;*/
    color: #6458b7;
}
#special {
    /*position: absolute;
    left: 77.9%;
    top: 50%;*/
    color: #6458b7;
}
/* Edit 2 END */
.boi:hover,
.iob:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #a193ff;
}
#footer {
    padding-left: 95%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <title>The Pragmatic Octopus</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
     <script src='script.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
     <h1 class="Octagon">The Pragmatic Octopus</h1>
     <p class="LT">Lee Townsend</p>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="boi">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="iob">Information</p>
        </a>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- Edit 2 -->
    <div id="wrapperForTheFirstImage">
        <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/406x38nlh/imageedit_1_3827627792        .jpg" alt="mmm~">
        <p>Here comes a very special boi!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapperForTheSecondImage">
        <img src="http://www.wonderslist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Blue-ringed-octopus.jpg" alt="~mmm">
        <p>He loves to pose for photos!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Edit 2 END -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
    &copy; Hecc
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit 1:

Added `max-width` to `#wrapper` to provide an example for (if i understand correctly):

> What do I need to do for proper positioning if somebody looks at this
>   with a higher pixel count screen?

Edit 2:

I think i know what u want now. Consider wrapping your `<img>` and `<p>` inside a div and position the div and not the img and the p tag separately.
I just updated the source to provide an example. (and removed the max-width thing)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed

Comment: What do I need to do for proper positioning if somebody looks at this with a higher pixel count screen?

Comment: you could also add an upper boundary for the width of a given element by adding `max-width: 1200px;` to it. Adding this to `#wrapper` will most likely do it. I will update my answer to give an example.

Comment: When I look at this website with a larger screen certain elements don't reach the desired location because they're positioned based off pixels. For example the text for the right image ends up being halfway across the page instead of under the image.